# How to maintain TCP connection to a transaction terminal when using socket connection in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Excuse me, I am trying to make an app that makes a TCP/IP connection to transaction terminal (those devices that accepts payments through cards) using Dart but there are some problems when I try to get response back from the device while it is processing payments.

I managed to actually establish a connection to one and managed to send ping message to it and received a response message back.

And for some reason when I try to initiate a sales request it managed to send and initiate the payment process, but it doesn't wait for the terminal to finish that process and get proper respond message. it just straight initiate socket.close(). Below is my code snippet for the connection

```
void connectTerminal(String sentData) async{
  const String ipAddv4='192.168.1.111'; //sample ip
  const int termPort= 9182; //sampleport

  try{
    final socket = await Socket.connect(ipAddv4, termPort);
    print('connection established');
    List<int> message = hex.encode(sentData);
    socket.add(message);

    socket.listen((List<int> data){
      final response = data;
      print('Received response from terminal: $response');
    });
    socket.close();

  } catch(e){
    print('Error: $e');
  }
}
```

Comment: `socket.listen` isn't going to 'wait' for data to arrive, so of course your code moves straight to the next line and closes the socket. Move the `close` somewhere else - for example in your message handler where you read and parse the response. When you eventually get the response and any sort of 'bye' message from the terminal, then, and only then, should you close the socket.

Comment: I see, but I only known have known to directly read and parse the response inside the socket.listen method. May you provide any other direct examples that I may follow? @RichardHeap

Comment: Actually nevermind, I managed to figure it out by using `await for` instead of `socket.listen`